# Power Query conditional join

Tags: join, conditional-statements, powerquery

I am trying to merge two tables in PowerQuery according to the following logic.

This is the first table:

[image]

and this is my second:

[image]

I have merged the two as follows through a full outer join using the ID column

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is this output

[image]

So what I was trying to achieve is:
How can I tell Power Query to give me the [day range] column (from the second table) for each record if [Departure time] is between [from] and [to]?

I am new to PowerQuery, so please try to explain your solution in simple terms.

Comment: Ref your comment to @horseyride, you could read Table2 into your query, and then add a custom column to Table 1 that references Table2 directly and provides your desired output. I suspect this may be slower than the List/expand/merge method shown, but it is doable.l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second table, in powerquery, add column, custom column with formula

```
= {  [#"from (mins)"]  ..  [#"to (mins)"]  }
```

use double arrows atop the new column to Expand to new rows

it will look like

[image]

File .. close and load to .. only create connection

Now go to first table.

Do a merge. Merge on ID column and on the new Custom column to the Deparure time column with left outer join

[image]

Expand the result to pull in the day range using the arrows atop the new column

[image]

full sample code for table 1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"ID", "Deparure time (in mins)"},Table2,{"ID", "Custom"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"day Range"}, {"day Range"})
in  #"Expanded Table2"
```

Comment: Hey horseyride, I followed your instructions and I got the result I wanted. Thank you. I think I have a basic understanding of your process which helps me to get why is working. I was wondering, is there also a formula I could use for the merge instead of expanding the second Table? I am asking because I could use the same process on other, more complex projects.
Thanks a lot for the clean explanation though.

Comment: If you don't want to do a merge for table1 then you can ignore table2 and just hardcode a colun ... custom column ... with formula = if ([Deparure time (in mins)] >=360 and [Deparure time (in mins)] <=660) then "Morning" else if ([Deparure time (in mins)] >=720 and [Deparure time (in mins)] <=900) then "Afternoon" else if ([Deparure time (in mins)] >=960 and [Deparure time (in mins)] <=1380) then "Evening" else null